# Why will copy and pasting chart across excels lose format?

Tags: vba, excel, charts, excel-charts

I am building a macro which copies a chart from one excel and pastes it into another. It worked previously but now seems to lose the date format for the x-axis of the chart. Even if I copyPicture, it still manages to lose the date format and show "jan yy" rather than "jan 16". I work in the Netherlands so years are represented by "jj" but both excel files are in US format and so is my computer.

Source Chart:
[image: The Source Chart here]

Output Chart:
[image: Output Chart here]

```
Sheets("Factsheet").ChartObjects("Chart 8").CopyPicture
core.Sheets("Output").Range("DD32").PasteSpecial
```

I have tried multiple configurations for Copy, CopyPicture(xlScreen or xlPrint) as well as for Paste (Paste, PasteSpecial xlPasteValues) but none seem to retain the format. If I use the following, it does work ONLY the first time the macro runs:

```
Sheets("Factsheet").ChartObjects("Chart 8").Activate
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
core.Sheets("Output").Paste
```

But this will not enable me to paste in a specific cell location unlike the first method and also I do not understand why it works the first time but not the second. Any help or ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: why move the chart? Have a template sheet with the chart assembled and working, then paste the fresh data in and do save.as ...

Comment: Unfortunately, need to take the chart and use it in another excel file with charts from a few other excel files so it has to be extracted

Comment: Put all the charts in one file... as per...

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, the charts pull data from separate files which are updated. I could create one file with these charts and their data but this would then require a duplication of updating data (or build a macro which does this) but was hoping there might be a simple solution to this... Thanks for the idea

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveChart.SaveChartTemplate Filename:="Temp Chart"
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
ActiveSheet.Sheets("YourSheetName").Paste
ActiveChart.ApplyChartTemplate "Temp Chart"
```

' This restores formatting on copy paste chart operations,  also when assigning the chart to new source ranges(since it also loses formatting)